# How to create a vertical scale bar in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, scale, legend

Wondering if anyone out there knows how to  create a vertical scale bar in ArcMap? With text I can adjust the angle. Is this possible with a scale bar as well?

Answer (score 7):

Once you are happy with the size of your scale bar you can right-click and convert to graphics, then the rotate and flip options are available in the drop-down menu. Just be sure not to accidentally resize it, the scale will no longer be accurate.

Comment: I'd rather the scale bar still be dynamic...if possible.

Answer (score 3):

The scale bar can only be horizontal. However, you can rotate the rest of your layout 90° so the printed map looks like the scale bar is vertical. To simplify the process and save your neck from getting a crick in it, you can draft your layout in the orientation opposite of what you expect to finish on.